# How to get selectedFieldValues from the ASPxGrid by clicking the checkbox command column?

Tags: javascript, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am loading the grid inside a popup, having ok button at the bottom of the grid,after data load I want to select the row from the grid and click on 'ok' button to assign the value in a textbox and hide the popup.

using clientside event for this. my code below.

```
function OnSearchADSOk(s, e) {
    e.processOnServer = false;

    grdSearchADSUser.GetSelectedFieldValues('UserName;FirstName;LastName;EmailAddress;KeyId', GetSearchADSSelectedValues);
}
```

grdSearchADSUser.GetSelectedFieldValues not fetching values from the grid.

Answer (score 0):

GetSelectedFieldValues doesn't return any selected values from the grid. You should process values in the GetSearchADSSelectedValues function. Code below from the [already answered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913283/devexpress-aspxgridview-getselectedfieldvalues-cant-get-values) should be

```
function GetSearchADSSelectedValues(result) {
  for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i ++)
    for(var j = 0; j <result[i].length; j++) {
        alert(result[i][j]);
  }
}
```